# How to set up JBoss with S3_Ping on AWS?

Tags: jboss, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm looking into running clustered JBoss on Amazon Web Services (AWS).

I'd like to try out S3_PING, i.e. making JBoss use an S3 bucket for dynamic node discovery etc, since no multicast is available. I found a piece of **[example config XML related to S3_Ping](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RunningInfinispanonAmazonWebServices)**, but I'm not sure where in JBoss installation you're supposed to configure this.

So, **what JBoss config files would I need to tweak to get S3_PING working**? Can anyone point me to a more complete example?

JBoss 5.1.0 GA. (This is probably more a JGroups/JBoss question than anything else. I've already got the S3 bucket for this set up, so no problem there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3_PING still seems to be an experimental feature and that might explain the missing documentation... Anyway, you can configure S3_PING to the jgroups-channelfactory-stacks.xml that is situated in `$JBOSS_HOME/server/all/cluster/jgroups-channelfactory.sar/META-INF/`.

See [JGroups Channel Protocol Stack Configuration](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossclustering/freezone/docs/cluster_guide/5.1/html/jgroups.chapt.html#d0e4143) in JBoss 5.1 Clustering Guide for more info on the contents of that file. Sadly, as mentioned before, it doesn't say anything about S3_PING. Basically, you can just replace the PING element with something like this:

```
<S3_PING secret_access_key="903rfj04rjg490" access_key="ji3gfo" location="bucketname/>
```

You might need to create the S3 bucket by yourself beforehand.

**UPDATE:**
It seems that JBoss 5.1 doesn't work with the newer JGroups versions that have support for S3_PING. By looking at JGroups JIRA, it seems that [there won't be any support for newer JGroups versions in JBoss 5.x ever](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JGRP-974). This means that you have to wait for the JBoss AS 6.0.0 MS3 version to get it, see the issue [here](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-7251). By looking at JBoss AS JIRA, it seems that MS3 won't be released in the near future. :(

**UPDATE 2010-03-17:**
I just noticed that the guys in the JBoss StormGrind project have made S3_PING work and [asked](http://community.jboss.org/docs/DOC-14388?uniqueTitle=false) more what versions they use. The use JBoss AS 6.0.0-MS2 and JGroups 2.6.13.GA. So, S3_PING was released before 2.8, even though some pages in JBoss site claim otherwise. I haven't yet tested this myself.

Comment: BTW, the AWS access keys that I used in the example are not mine, so no need to remind me of that! :)

Comment: Thanks Kaitsu. That seems to be the right file. 

However, I'm running into "org.jgroups.ChannelException: unable to setup the protocol stack: unable to load class for protocol S3_PING (either as an absolute - S3_PING - or relative - org.jgroups.protocols.S3_PING - package name)". Turns out that the latest stable JBoss (5.1.0) ships with JGroups 2.6.10, while S3_Ping was added in JGroups 2.8 :(

Comment: @jonik: Yes, so it seems. See my updated answer for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps late but wanted to point out that EAP5 does have S3_PING support. As for community distribution JBoss AS 7 has that support (what you already know from Kaitsu's replay) but the feature is now supported.

For EAP, you could go to the official [EAP documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/) that describes how to enable clustering with the Red Hat EAP AMIs. For JBoss Application Server 7 you may find [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/177941) valuable.

Answer (score 1):

[S3_PING was added in JGroups 2.6.12](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JGRP-1022) is part of JBoss AS 6.0.0.M2

Comment: Yeah, thanks, we just realised the same thing. Seems my original source (http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RunningInfinispanonAmazonWebServices) was wrong on this one, talking about 2.8. **Edit** I see it's now been corrected... by you, apparently :-)

Answer (score 0):

S3 is great, you should give the CirrAS AMI's a spin, check out the wiki article: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CirrASRunningOnAmazonEC2 - backend instances use S3_PING for discovery.

For AS5, a viable solution to not having S3_PING would be to use a GossipRouter (included in jgroups) and then using TUNNEL configuration (if you extract the jgroups.jar archive, there are configurations inside for all different options).